# Laravel Query Built or Eloquent ORM?

Tags: laravel

What's the best way to work with complex queries? it is sometimes difficult to use Eloquent to query multiple tables

Comment: What do you define as a "complex query"? Your question is incredibly vague, and it's unlikely anyone is going to be able to help you unless you provide more information.

Comment: imagine joining 4 or more tables of the database, it would be easier to use eloquent ORM or query built, sometimes I have difficulty joining many tables

Comment: Depends if you want to do something `DB::table('whatever')->join(...)->join(...)->join(...)`, or `Model::with(['relationship1', 'relationship2', ...])`. There's pros and cons to both approach, but neither is "better" or "the best". This is also a bit of an opinionated question, which is considered off-topic for Stackoverflow.